# Haproxy %rt field size

Tags: haproxy

I want to configure GUID filed in Haproxy, example which introduced [here](https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/hapee/1-8r1/onepage/#4.2-unique-id) - this format has more than 128-bit, but I thought, I can do without all those fields, I'm looking forward to use **%Ts** fields with **%rt** field. As I understood **%Ts** is 32 bit integer number -- time in seconds, but I'm not understand which size is **%rt** field, in link above 16 bit, but I thought for request counter it's too small.

So my question is: which size has **%rt** flag?

Answer (score 0):

As described in the doc it's a `numeric` type as shown in [Custom log format](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.0/configuration.html#8.2.4) which is formatted as `%04X` from `uniq_id`as you can see in the source.
https://github.com/haproxy/haproxy/blob/master/src/log.c#L2819.

The `uniq_id` is from type `unsigned int` https://github.com/haproxy/haproxy/blob/master/src/log.c#L1909